# Default diff in bazaar gui

Tags: bazaar, bazaar-plugins

I'm using bzr latest version (2.4.1.1) with QBZR.
My default diff is defined as exteranl software (beyond compare).

When i press "diff" in commit window , the external software will run.
but when i press on the "diff" option under modified files , the builtin diff program will run.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be a bug which you can report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/qbzr

(I think you will get a quicker response there)

Comment: thanks @AmanicA.i reported this bug and update when i get response

Comment: For others following along this is the bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/qbzr/+bug/854738